# How to get the name or ip of a proxy server in a managed network?

Tags: java, urlconnection, proxy-server

i need to be able to access certain urls programmatically . I am using URLConnection as follows

```
URL url = new URL(http,         
                  myProxy.com, // I need to know this parameter   
                  -1,              
                  http://www.example.com/);
```

How do I get the name of the proxy server used in a managed network.

when i use a browser like chrome it connects me with the proxy server that makes requests to the internet . How do i get the name of the proxy server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a java [ProxySelector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) class to do it, her is short example of it'usage from java [proxy configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/networking/proxie_config.html) guide:

```
private Proxy findProxy(URI uri)
{
   try
   {
      ProxySelector selector = ProxySelector.getDefault();
      List<Proxy> proxyList = selector.select(uri);
      if (proxyList.size() > 1)
           return proxyList.get(0);
   }
   catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
   {
   }
   return Proxy.NO_PROXY;
}
```

To get a host name and IP address, you can use an InetSocketAddress, which you can get from Proxy instance:

```
InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address(); 
if(addr != null) { 
  System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName()); 
  System.out.println("proxy port : " + addr.getPort()); 
}
```

But as I know, it's needed to set a system property to do it:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
```

One more solution is to use a [proxy-vole library](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) to do it. Here is some [usage examples](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/wiki/UsageExamples).